# Wt Database Wt::Dbo

Tags: wt

I am trying to learn Wt for a project and right now I am trying to learn database part of it.

I am stuck at the beginning. I am trying to learn it from dbo tutorials (there is a tutorial in the website http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/dbo/tutorial.html#_installing_tt_wt_dbo_tt) which is in the examples that comes within the Wt package (tutorial1.C)

I am using Qt compiler (5.) in ubuntu. I have build the Wt::Dbo library as it says in the website tutorial (linked above). the problem is it still gives an error which is;

> cannot find lGL
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the code that comes within Wt (directly copied from tutorial1.C)

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 Emweb bvba, Kessel-Lo, Belgium.
 *
 * See the LICENSE file for terms of use.
 */

/*****
 * This file is part of the Wt::Dbo tutorial:
 * http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/dbo/tutorial.html
 *****/

#include <Wt/Dbo/Dbo>
#include <Wt/Dbo/backend/Sqlite3>
#include <string>

namespace dbo = Wt::Dbo;

/*****
 * Dbo tutorial section 2. Mapping a single class
 *****/

class User {
public:
  enum Role {
    Visitor = 0,
    Admin = 1,
    Alien = 42
  };

  std::string name;
  std::string password;
  Role        role;
  int         karma;

  template<class Action>
  void persist(Action& a)
  {
    dbo::field(a, name,     "name");
    dbo::field(a, password, "password");
    dbo::field(a, role,     "role");
    dbo::field(a, karma,    "karma");
  }
};

void run()
{
  /*****
   * Dbo tutorial section 3. A first session
   *****/

  /*
   * Setup a session, would typically be done once at application startup.
   *
   * For testing, we'll be using Sqlite3's special :memory: database. You
   * can replace this with an actual filename for actual persistence.
   */
  dbo::backend::Sqlite3 sqlite3(":memory:");
  sqlite3.setProperty("show-queries", "true");
  dbo::Session session;
  session.setConnection(sqlite3);

  session.mapClass<User>("user");

  /*
   * Try to create the schema (will fail if already exists).
   */
  session.createTables();

  {
    dbo::Transaction transaction(session);

    User *user = new User();
    user->name = "Joe";
    user->password = "Secret";
    user->role = User::Visitor;
    user->karma = 13;

    dbo::ptr<User> userPtr = session.add(user);
  }

  /*****
   * Dbo tutorial section 4. Querying objects
   *****/

  {
    dbo::Transaction transaction(session);

    dbo::ptr<User> joe = session.find<User>().where("name = ?").bind("Joe");

    std::cerr << "Joe has karma: " << joe->karma << std::endl;

    dbo::ptr<User> joe2 = session.query< dbo::ptr<User> >
      ("select u from user u").where("name = ?").bind("Joe");
  }

  {
    dbo::Transaction transaction(session);

    typedef dbo::collection< dbo::ptr<User> > Users;

    Users users = session.find<User>();

    std::cerr << "We have " << users.size() << " users:" << std::endl;

    for (Users::const_iterator i = users.begin(); i != users.end(); ++i)
      std::cerr << " user " << (*i)->name
        << " with karma of " << (*i)->karma << std::endl;
  }

  /*****
   * Dbo tutorial section 5. Updating objects
   *****/

  {
    dbo::Transaction transaction(session);

    dbo::ptr<User> joe = session.find<User>().where("name = ?").bind("Joe");

    joe.modify()->karma++;
    joe.modify()->password = "public";
  }

  {
    dbo::Transaction transaction(session);
    dbo::ptr<User> joe = session.find<User>().where("name = ?").bind("Joe");
    if (joe)
      joe.remove();
  }

  {
    dbo::Transaction transaction(session);

    dbo::ptr<User> silly = session.add(new User());
    silly.modify()->name = "Silly";
    silly.remove();
  }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  run();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem occurs because of the .pro file. I am not sure how it works but the problem is gone when I replaced the pro file as I first implemented it (copy-paste from another .pro file with very little modifications and there should not be any differences between the first one the the last one).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand that Qt is not a compiler. It is a framework for development of cross platform applications and GUIs. I believe, you may be also using Qt Creator which is an IDE. Actual compiler may be gcc, clang, msvc or some other. The linking error indicates that you are build it as a gui application. Adding 'CONFIG -= qt' in your pro file will solve the issue. Alternatively, while creating new project choose Non-Qt Project->Plain C++ Application.